# Mysql Database Backup Using Batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to backup my MySql databases on Windows via a batch file. It works fine.
but i want to remove the default use "database" and create "database"  command.from that .sql file which is by default created while creating backup.

these are the lines i want to remove before taking backup for each .sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `database name` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

USE `database name`;

Answer (score 1):

Ya I got the answer from mysql official site.
I have used **'--databases'** in my batch file. to backup all databases.present in server.
just removing that and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
--no-create-db
```

> Do not write CREATE DATABASE statements

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_create-options

Comment: Thank's For your reply but how to remove use "database".